# How do I get Coronasdk files in to xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, coronasdk

I built a basic app using Coronasdk as they said I could publish the app to apple and all the major markets. When I click build in Corona I get two options. Build for simulator and build for device. But at this point I have tried everything I can think of to get the files in to xcode for publishing. I have Googled for days with no luck.

Comment: You actually don't need to use Xcode at all with Corona sdk. Have you created distribution certificates and provisioning profiles? Take a look here: [link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/iOSBuild/index.html)

Comment: @SamHogan I guess I'm just not getting how to get the app to apple. With Appery.io I have to load the .ipa in to xcode to submit the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona SDK, after successfully building a distribution app will output a .zip file in the folder you defined for the App builds.  This zip file will be named the same as the folder your main.lua is in.  Thus if you're app is in a folder called "awesomeapp", you will get a file:  awesomeapp.zip.

Run the **Application Loader** app.  You can just type in Application Loader into Spotlight search, or launch it from Xcode's menus:   Xcode->Open Developer Tool->Application Loader

When this starts, you can select the .zip file to upload.  This is how you get apps to iTunes Connect.